# Unknown icon in wingpanel

Tags: wingpanel

I have an icon in wingpanel which I cannot assign to any app. Probably I uninstalled an app - but I do not know wich one it was.

[image]

Is there any way to find out which indicator is not loading here? When there is a wingpanel config file, I think I would be able to find out which app is affected.

Thank you.

Comment: I can see you aren't using the default icon theme for elementary OS.  Try changing to default.

Comment: I tried - but almost the same. It is just displayed the default "unknown icon".